# Dynamic IPs for Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I need to setup a multi-node Hadoop cluster. So far, I have done installations using static IP addresses for each of the cluster nodes. However, in my latest cluster, I need to work with DHCP assigned nodes. So I am wondering, how should I get the cluster working and survive restarts etc.

Is it mandatory to have static IP address for the cluster nodes or can we get it working with dynamic IPs as well?

Any expert guidance please.

Answer (score 0):

For standalone and pseudo-distributed modes, you can get going on dynamic IP address for it runs on a single node. 
For fully distributed mode, the nodes are identified with the **file masters and slaves** located in '**HADOOP_HOME/conf**'. These names are hosts which have been described in '**/etc/hosts**'. So, when IP of any node changes, Hadoop cannot identify the machines or nodes or hosts (even if identified, these nodes have no Hadoop configured). Thus, you **cannot achieve the fully distributed Hadoop setup**.

Get your DHCP configured on a router if you can. Else **install DHCP** on all of the nodes. And get going!!